# launch.vs.json file configuration for external executable on windows subsystem for linux

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, gdb, shared-libraries, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In the Visual Studio 2019 + WSL. I have the CMake project that builds some.so library. 
My point is to debug with gdb on the WSL, the executable that is in the other directory. That executable uses the built library.

I've tried to set the project target, the cwd and the program properties in the launch.vs.json

```
'''{
  "type": "cppdbg",
  "name": "some",
  "project": "CMakeLists.txt",
  "projectTarget": "some",
  "cwd": "path/to/some/executable/directory",
  "program": "path/to/some/executable",
  "MIMode": "gdb",
  "externalConsole": true,
  "remoteMachineName": "${debugInfo.remoteMachineName}",
  "pipeTransport": {
    "pipeProgram": "${debugInfo.shellexecPath}",
    "pipeArgs": [
      "/s",
      "${debugInfo.remoteMachineId}",
      "/p",
      "${debugInfo.parentProcessId}",
      "/c",
      "${debuggerCommand}",
      "--tty=${debugInfo.tty}"
    ],
    "debuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
  },
  "setupCommands": [
    {
      "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
      "ignoreFailures": true
    }
  ],
  "visualizerFile": "${debugInfo.linuxNatvisPath}",
  "showDisplayString": true
}
```

'''

Visual Studio 2019 asks me to choose Startup Item and cannot see the executable.